# How to put button on header in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a header area before my ui-view. I don't want to include my header in every template file. How can I use a directive or something to get a button on top of the page?

The button depends on the pages.

Here some examples:

My main index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="smarthome">
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/ionic/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <section id="content">
        <div class="page-header row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" ng-show="isBack()" ng-click="goBack()">
                    <i class="ion ion-arrow-left-c"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h1>blabla</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <!-- BUTTON HERE -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you link a controller to the header and use ng-show in the top div of the header?
Like this:

```
 <body>
    <section id="content" ng-controller="headerCtrl">
        <div class="page-header row" ng-show="isVisible()>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" ng-show="isBack()" ng-click="goBack()">
                    <i class="ion ion-arrow-left-c"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h1>blabla</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <!-- BUTTON HERE -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats a good idea but I want to create the button in the template with an direction. It's a bit more complex because I have different sites that use the same app with different templates.

Comment: You have different applications using this app as an API? or different routes on the same build need to access the global header?

Comment: Yesusing this app as api. Is there any way to create a direction for this purpose? Like in ionicframework.

Comment: Can you turn the header into a directive and require a boolean attribute that determines whether or not the button is visible?

Comment: No, because the text and the ng-click event is not always the same

Comment: But i can turn the header into an directive. Sure.

Comment: Well it seems like you need some logic in your factory to determine whether or not the directive displays. It's tough to provide a solution without knowing your exact use case. Can you provide more code above?

Comment: Ok, i will post more code in a couple of hours. Thank your for your time mate

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain the whole situation. It should be simular to ion-nav-buttons in ionicframework. The idea is to have a html tag (directive), that lets you fill in an area in the header outside the loaded template from the template. At first I had the idea to use $rootScope, but with $rootScope the button would stay on the next page and the button must be page specific.

Comment: So somewhere in the template I use: <header-button><button class="btn" ng-click="whatever()">My foo button</button></header-button> and the button appears in the header, but only on this page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. You could add the button function in ng-click by adding the function

```
angular.module('app', ['LocalStorageModule'])
     .run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {  
               $rootScope.yourFunction = function () {
                   console.log("clicked here");
                }
    }]);
```